# Handling dynamic checkbox in react-native using hooks

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying implement `react-native-elements` checkbox. In my case i need to have multiple checkbox based on the array. Below is my code -

```
const CheckTest = () => {
    const [check, setCheck] = useState(false);
    const label = [
        {
            name: 'first'
        },
        {
            name: 'second'
        },
        {
            name: 'third'
        },
        {
            name: 'fourth'
        }]
    const onValueChange = () => {
        setCheck(check => !check)
    }
    return (
        <View style={{ paddingTop: 20 }}>
            {label.map(item => {
                return <CheckBox
                    title={item.name}
                    checked={check}
                    onPress={(val) => onValueChange(val)}
                    key={item.name}
                />
            })}


        </View>
    )
}
```

Problem is in this code is when i select/deselect one checkbox all checkbox are getting checked/unchecked.

I aasume this is happening because of `check state` as it is applying to all.

How to handle this scnario?

Thanks in advance !!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
const CheckTest = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([
        {
            name: 'first'
        },
        {
            name: 'second'
        },
        {
            name: 'third'
        },
        {
            name: 'fourth'
        }]); 



    const onValueChange = (item, index) => {
        const newData = [...data];
        newData[index].isCheck = !item.isCheck;
        setData(newData);
    }

    return (
        <View style={{ paddingTop: 20 }}>
            {data.map((item, index) => {
                return <CheckBox
                    title={item.name}
                    checked={item.isCheck || false}
                    onPress={(val) => onValueChange(item, index)}
                    key={item.name}
                />
            })}


        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: what is `item.ischeck` here

Comment: `ischeck` is a `key` here like `name` and we're defining it on runtime so it would work surely. You can also define it in `[{name: 'first', ischeck: false },...]`

Comment: this data is coming from a API, do i need to add ischeck in the api data?

Comment: No, of course not. You can do this on runtime as I answered

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani i am having same problem exactly but this solution doesn't work for me  `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'newData[index].isCheck = !item.isCheck')`