# Handling checkbox in react-native using map()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, checkbox, react-hooks

I am using `'@react-native-community/checkbox'` as I am retrieving data from database and rendering it whiting checkboxes using map function, the problem is when I check one box all boxes checked as well and same when I uncheck
the problem is with state of each checkbox but I have no idea how to handle that as I want to make only sleeted checkbox being checked and get all its data into one array for further process.

here the data I am rendering as checkboxes:

```
{"id": "12345", "price": 5, "text": "Reload"}
```

and this is the code of map function:

```
{data.map((b, index) => {
         return (
                   <View key={b.id} style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', width: windowWidth, paddingLeft: 15, paddingRight: 15 }}>
                   <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row-reverse', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                          <CheckBox
                             disabled={false}
                             value={checked}
                             onValueChange={(newValue) => { setIschecked(newValue) }}

                            />

                          <Text>{b.text}   </Text>
                   </View>

                   <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>

                         <Text style={{ fontSize: 10, fontWeight: 'bold', color: COLORS.darkgray }}>  
                            {" USD " + b.price} 
                         </Text>
                   </View>



              </View>
           )
       })}
```

I found a question same as my problem exactly which [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64888702/handling-dynamic-checkbox-in-react-native-using-hooks) but unfortunately that doesn't work for me

thanks and advance

Comment: If you have an array of items, you cannot use just one flag to store state for all of them (unless you want radio boxes), you need to have an array of checked items instead so it'll be `value={checked[b.id]}` and  `const newArray = checked.slice(), newArray[b.id]=newValue;setIschecked(newArray)`

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova i got this error `ypeError: checked.slice is not a function. (In 'checked.slice()', 'checked.slice' is undefined)`. what i did i passed `newValue` to function the do the following `const newArray = checked.slice(); newArray[b.id]=newValue;setIschecked(newArray)`

Comment: You need to initiate checked as an array when you can useState

Comment: so it will be something like this right? `const [checked, setIschecked] = useState([])`

Comment: Yes,that should do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to store the state of your checkboxes separate from the data itself, in React state.

First create an empty object on first render, this will act as a map of checkbox `id`s to their checked value:

```
const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState({});
```

Inside your `map` you can find the value of that particular checkbox based on `b.id`:

```
value={checked[b.id]}
```

Finally in your callback, make sure you update the right value in `checked` also based on `b.id`:

```
onValueChange={(newValue) => { setChecked({...checked, [b.id]: newValue}) }}
```

Put it all together:

```
const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState({});

// rest of your render function

     {data.map((b, index) => {
         return (
                   <View key={b.id} style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', width: windowWidth, paddingLeft: 15, paddingRight: 15 }}>
                   <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row-reverse', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                          <CheckBox
                             disabled={false}
                             value={checked[b.id]}
                             onValueChange={(newValue) => { setChecked({...checked, [b.id]: newValue}) }}

                            />

                          <Text>{b.text}   </Text>
                   </View>

                   <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>

                         <Text style={{ fontSize: 10, fontWeight: 'bold', color: COLORS.darkgray }}>  
                            {" USD " + b.price} 
                         </Text>
                   </View>



              </View>
           )
       })}
```

Comment: thank you so much, may i know how I can make this call back `setChecked({...checked, [b.id]: newValue}` in function, mean i want to call a function in `onValueChange` props and the checked boxes status update happened in called function

Comment: @anie I'm not sure what you mean. You want to still call `setIsChecked()` inside of the callback function? The `onValueChange` callback can be whatever function you want, just refactor accordingly. I updated my answer assuming you still want to call `setIsCheck()`. But if that doesn't answer your question, then please ask it in a new question as it sounds like a separate issue.